# How to deploy laravel and vue app separately

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

When i work on localhost apache it's fine but when i deploy vue on netlify and laravel on 000webhost the vue app failed to fetch or post data from the laravel on 000webhost
i'm sure that laravel work well with mysql and i tested that
but for example when i login or fetch data from vue that's consume the laravel app
i found that on
the console :

```
net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

also on the response

```
failed to load response data no resource with given identifier
```

Updated:
the problem with the 000webhost i don't know why but the vue on netlify interact with the laravel on local succssfully but with the laravel on 000webhost that's happening
any help please or any suggestion
because i hate errors like this!

Answer (score 0):

The solution by deploy the api service on another server because 000webhost  don't support something like api methods so it's work in paid plan.